# How to use "ORDER BY FIELD" to sort the result of a SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, field

If there is a data shown as below;

```
id  cnt_stamp    
1  999 
2  3
3  9
4  3 
5  1000
6  30
```

If an input is (4, 1, 2, 3) in this order, I would like to get only (3, 999, 3, 9).
To achieve this, I created a SQL

```
SELECT `cnt_stamp`
FROM `stm_events`
ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 4, 1, 2, 3);
```

But it returns (1000, 30, 3, 999, 3, 9) instead. How should I fix my SQL to achieve my goal? Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Do you want to display (1000, 30) at the end , or not show it at all ?

Comment: If possible, I dont want to show (1000, 30) even at the end... @a1ex07

Comment: Need to tag with database engine. "Field" is a non-standard extension, so this will be mysql-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FIELD` will assign `NULL` to any non matching `id`, and nulls sort first by default in MySQL.  If you don't want to see non matching items at all you may just add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT cnt_stamp
FROM stm_events
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 4, 1, 2, 3);
```

If you want to see all your data, with non matching `id` values at the end, then reverse the order of the field list and sort descending:

```
SELECT cnt_stamp
FROM stm_events
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3, 2, 1, 4) DESC;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I didnt wanna show non matching items at all ,so I took the first one, and I worked! This is exactly what I wanted, and your explanation helped me to understand what's wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE` function :

```
SELECT `cnt_stamp` 
  FROM `stm_events` 
 ORDER BY COALESCE(`id`,FIELD(`id`,4,1,2,3));
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb0e65/5)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! `COALESCE` might be a good idea, but another person already gave me a good solution, and I took it.